# Webpack watch build compilation

Tags: webpack

When i run `webpack --progress --colors --watch` and i edit a CSS file, webpack build CSS AND JS bundle.

Do you know if it's possible to build only bundle.css if css file is modified ? And same for js file.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are looking for **`HRM`** hot module replacement. It will build only changed portion but sometimes when it fail to to that it build the whole application.

Comment: I don't use HRM, i've my Apache server with PHP. It's don't work without HRM ?

Comment: No i don't think that there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

yes , you can use the extract-text plugin to get the css out of the js bundles. So you will have the css in its own bundle. The watchmode does only rebuild the part of the bundle that you have modified on. It does usually only take around a secound to build the changes.

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                loader: "css-loader"
            }) }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

This will get all the css into a style.css bundle.
It can be made even more modular as own css bundles per entry point.